# What is the square root of $i^4$?

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

What is the $\sqrt{i^4}$?

$i^4$ = $(i^2)^2$ So is $\sqrt{i^4}$ = $\sqrt{(i^2)^2}$ = $i^2$ = $-1$?

Or is $\sqrt{i^4}$ = $\sqrt{1}$ = $1$?

When I plug it into my TI-89 Titanium, I get $1$.

**Edit:** I now see why $i^4 \neq -1$. $$\sqrt{x^2} = \left|{x}\right| $$ So$$\sqrt{(i^2)^2} = \left|i^2\right| = \left|-1\right| = 1$$

Comment: $\sqrt{(i^2)^2}\ne i^2$, for the same reason $\sqrt{(-1)^2}\ne -1$.

Comment: I will point out to anyone reading this after all this time that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ is *only valid for real values of $x$*.  $\sqrt{(1+i)^2}$ does actually equal $1+i$ for example (*it had not crossed the branchcut*) and does not equal $|1+i|$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is $1$.  The reason it is not $-1$ is because, to get there, you inherently split up the square root into a product of square roots as

$$\sqrt{(i^2)^2} = \sqrt{i^2} \sqrt{i^2}$$

This is not valid for nonreal numbers.

Comment: Why is it not valid?

Comment: $$\sqrt{(-1) (-4)} = \sqrt{4} = 2$$

or

$$\sqrt{(-1) (-4)} = \sqrt{-1} \sqrt{-4} = i (2 i) = -2$$

Clearly, splitting the square root is not valid when the square roots are not real.

Comment: So it's not that there are just two answers?

Comment: @gangqinlaohu: no, there is a unique answer.  There must be, otherwise it would be impossible to develop the system of complex numbers consistently.

Comment: "otherwise it would be impossible to develop the system of complex numbers consistently." how so? there are two solutions to every equation of the form, `x^2=y` unless `y=0`. If `y<0` there are two complex solutions. If you define the square root of y as the solution to this equation, then there are definitely two solutions to every square root. As a result, complex numbers are commutative under square-roots and `-2` is a real root of `4`, since clearly `(-2)*(-2)=4`.

Answer (score 4):

$i^4=1$, and $1$ has two square-roots, $1$ and $-1$.  However when you say **the** square-root, I cleverly deduce that you mean the principal square-root.  By the usual conventions that is $1$.

Answer (score 3):

There is no “the” square root of a complex number, because there is no square root function definable as continuous on all of $\mathbb C$. The complex number $i^4=1$ has two square roots, and in the complex domain there’s (only a) little to help us choose one of them over the other. If you’re only in the real domain $\mathbb R$, then a nonnegative number has a preferred square root, the positive one; but once you jump up to the complexes, the story gets much more confusing.

Answer (score -2):

I think it should be $-1$

note that $$i=e^{\left(\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi\right)i}$$ $$i^4=e^{4\left(\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi\right)i}=e^{\left(2\pi+8k\pi\right)i}$$
$$\sqrt{i^4}=e^{\frac12\left(2\pi+8k\pi\right)i}=e^{\left(\pi+4k\pi\right)i}=-1$$

Comment: $i^4 = 1$, so shouldn't $\sqrt{i^4}$ = $\sqrt{1}$ = $1$?

Comment: the real operator $\sqrt{  }$ defines in one-one condition. But in complex, there are different branches. For example, since $e^{\theta i}=e^{(\theta+2k\pi)i}$. so $\log e^{\theta i}=(\theta+2k\pi) i$. See there are different values? so whenever deal with complex number, change it to the form $re^{\theta i}$